# How to prevent the last table cell from overlapping with the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikeyboard

I have a chat app that displays the messages in a table view.  When I invoke the keyboard, I want:

1. The table view to scroll to the bottom
2. I want there to be no overlap between any messages and the keyboard.

```swift
@objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let keyBoardFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyBoardFrame!, from: view.window)
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardViewEndFrame.height
        
        tableView.scrollToBottom() { indexPath in
            let rectofCell = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
            let lastCellFrame = self.tableView.convert(rectofCell, from: self.view.window)
            if lastCellFrame.origin.y + lastCellFrame.size.height > keyboardViewEndFrame.origin.y {
                let overlap = lastCellFrame.origin.y + lastCellFrame.size.height - keyboardViewEndFrame.origin.y
                self.tableView.frame.origin.y = -overlap
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true, completion: ((IndexPath) -> Void)? = nil) {
        let sections = self.numberOfSections
        let rows = self.numberOfRows(inSection: sections - 1)
        if (rows > 0){
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rows - 1, section: sections - 1)
            self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            completion?(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

The value for `rectOfCell` shows `(0.0, 5305.333518981934, 375.0, 67.33333587646484)` and the converted value `(0.0, 9920.000185648601, 375.0, 67.33333587646484)` and the table view disappears out of the screen.

I only want to move the table view upward if the last message overlaps with the eventual position of the keyboard. For example, when the keyboard is invoked (either when the table view is already at the bottom or not at the bottom), the table view shouldn't move upward if the appearance of the keyboard doesn't cover the messages (i.e., there is only one message).

Comment: Rather than moving the table view upwards, how about just reducing its height by the keyboard height first, then scrolling it to the bottom? Unless I'm missing something, it seems simpler that way. You don't need to calculate the last cell's frame or anything fiddly like that.

Comment: @Sweeper thank you. I haven't seen this approach when I did some research, but it seems meeting all my requirements. Feel free to post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manage `tableView.frame` for such a thing. You just need to make sure that when keyboard appears, tableView adds necessary contentInset value from bottom so that user can still see all the content inside tableView with the keyboard still on screen.

All you need is this -

```
// when keyboard appears
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: 0)
tableView.contentInset = insets
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets

// when keyboard disappears
let insets: UIEdgeInsets = .zero
tableView.contentInset = insets
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
```